# True or false: in a OO language that does not have pointers, all objects are references

Tags: pointers, reference, programming-languages

Is it true that, in an object-oriented language that does not have explicit pointers, all objects must be references.

Here a reference is like SO defines in the tag [reference](/questions/tagged/reference):

> A reference is a value that enables a program to indirectly access a particular datum, such as a variable or a record, in the computer's memory or in some other storage device.

Here is my reasoning. Consider what happens if we pass a data structure as an argument to a function. That data structure may be large, so we definitely don’t want a copy to be created. In a language that has explicit pointers, we would pass a pointer to the data structure. In a language that does not have explicit pointers, the argument better behave as a pointer implicitly, and provide indirect access to the data structure. In other words, it better be a reference.

A reply is needed only if the statement with which I began the question is false. In that case, I and the future readers would be helped by an explanation of why the above reasoning is not sound.

Comment: This question is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422244/)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "all objects must be references". This is clearly not the case: objects are objects, a raw reference could not provide all the behaviour expected from objects. A reference may refer *to* an object but it is not equiavlent.

Comment: IMO the problem with these kinds of questions is that "pointer" and "reference" aren't as clearly-defined as one might imagine when not talking about a specific language. A "C++ reference" is pretty well defined, as is a "C pointer". But a "Java reference" is quite different from a "C++ reference", so if you talk about a hypothetical language-agnostic "reference", you have to define **what exactly** you mean by that. What semantics/restrictions/definitions do you associate with that term for the purpose of that question. A frequent assumption is to use the C++ definition.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I mean that accessing an object uses indirection through a pointer stored implicitly with the object.

Comment: Can you define what exactly distinguishes a pointer from a reference for the purpose of this question?

Comment: @JoachimSauer A pointer is a value of a pointer type. A pointer can exist only in a language providing explicit pointers such as C and C++. A reference is a value of a reference type. Variables of a reference type refer to a value stored in memory, but access to that data through the variable is indirect. You can think of references in Python or C#, but I think that this understanding is language-agnostic. In particular, it holds for C++ references as well.

Comment: "A reference is a value of a reference type" is quite tautological and not really useful. Fundamentally I ask you to distinguish between https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming) or any other definition that you have in mind.

Comment: @JoachimSauer With references, there is no dereferencing operator and no pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Depending on what you consider as a "reference" the answer might vary. Consider Python for instance, everything in Python is an object (even integers, functions, classes themselves!). But if you consider that like C++ references if you pass an integer value to a function and modify that variable in the function it will modify it in the caller as well, that won't be so (Because, well integer objects are immutable, when you change the value of the variable it just creates a new integer object and assigns that to the variable local to the function).

Comment: This post is unclear, unresearched & way too vague & general. It is filled with generic terms with specific meanings only in different languages/contexts & you don't give your precise meanings & confuse language semantics/source notions of parameter passing with implementation notions & show misconceptions. Also you are de facto asking for explanation not just yes or no & yes or no questions are generally poor anyway. If you force yourself to be very clear you might be able to ask a reasonably scoped answerable question but it will still likely off-topic as not a practical programming issue.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 5):

I think that "[...] all objects must be references" is wrong for two reasons, the first of which might be nit-picky:

1. objects *aren't* references or pointers. They might be referenced using references and pointers, but they themselves are collections of data (and sometimes code). This reason can be fixed by rephrasing the question as "all objects are handled via references" or something similar.
2. "[...] we definitely don’t want a copy to be created." is a reasonable assumption for a general-purpose language, but some languages are very specialized and might exist in a niche where the drawbacks of copying large objects for each method/function call are considered worthwhile.

Fundamentally I think that all object-oriented languages will require support for some kind of [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) to their objects. Whether that support comes in the form of simple [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) or something closer to [C++ references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) is up to the language.

Comment: I find the second reason nit-picky as well. So, for all the regular intents and purposes, you seem to agree with the original statement.

Comment: IMO the nitpickyness depends on what definition of various terms you use, since those very definitions are the things we argue about here. If we can't agree on the definitions, then we won't be able to agree on the answer. You seem to be looking for some "universally true answer" without strictly defining what you mean by each word. I think that approach is not likely to work out.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning If you want to nitpick, statement "All object are references" will never be true, because references are merely pointers to data that is stored in some other location. If you carefully read this answer you will see that point 1. says that.

Comment: Also, many languages have records or structures that are not objects, but value types which similarly to objects are capable of storing large amounts of data, but because they are value types that data will be copied around. And some of those languages don't have pointers either. So your generalization is pretty useless, because every language will have some similarities with others, but also notable differences.

Comment: Additionally, when it comes to passing parameters languages differ greatly in what kind(s) of parameter passing they support.

Answer (score 2):

The statement itself is a category error (an object *is not* a reference), but tweaking it to the most likely meaning:

> all objects must be [handled by] references [in the implementation]

Then it is demonstrably ***False***.

There are implementations of object oriented languages that simplify "reference types" to "value types" when it can be proven not to make a semantic difference. One such technique is [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer) which folds data into pointer/reference; this is used by the [PyPy Python runtime](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/interpreter-optimizations.html#integers-as-tagged-pointers) and [V8 JavaScript runtime](https://v8.dev/blog/pointer-compression) to implement integer objects as plain values, for example. This means the implementation handles *some* objects by reference and *some* objects by value.

Generally, any non-recursive, immutable object can be implemented without references. Whether this is advantageous in an individual case ("we definitely don’t want a copy") is up to the runtime/compiler to decide.